# How to enable internet connection sharing in C#

Tags: c#, networking

I have been Googling and searching in stackoverflow, but none of them are giving a simple and direct answer to

> How to check the checkbox of **allow other network users to connect
>   through this computer's internet connection** and select the hosted
>   network from the comboBox menu programmatically in C# .

I have successfully created the hosted network through C# but nnow for the last few days I am stuck at how to share the internet through this hosted network through C#.

Please help.

Comment: If you run process explorer and then [enable ICS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770930(v=ws.10).aspx) by using the group policy editor you might learn which registry keys and values are involved.

Comment: I tried to run process explorer, but it is very difficult to locate which process is responsible for that task. Do you know the specific process name ?

Comment: mmc.exe is the process that runs the control panel plugins